# How to get a similar behaviour of Matlab findchangepts function in python?

Tags: python, signal-processing

I want to replicate the matlab findchangepts in python.

I have this signal.
[Original Signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDUUi.jpg)

This is the matlab code.

```
findchangepts(signal,'MinThreshold',50,'Statistic','rms', 'MinDistance',100);
```

I can't find a python package that can replicate it. (I tried with ruptures library)

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25wPL.jpg)

Comment: do it yourself, cut signal into frames (with overlapping), calculate RMS of each frame, find places where this RMS changes by much (using `np.diff`,? maybe with some smoothing of the "RMS signal")

Comment: ruptures is definitely worth a try and it includes the same algorithm as used in findchangepts. But if anybody needs a Bayesian alternative, one possible tool in Python is the BEAST method my team developed, which is available at https://pypi.org/project/Rbeast/. Unlike classical algorithms such as findchangepts or ruptures, BEAST tells not just when the changepoints occur but also quantifies the probability of changepoint occurrence. See below for a quick illustration.